# How to test if onpropertychange is supported or not?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'd like to know if an input element has changed, I learned that I can listen to `onpropertychange` in IE and `oninput` in other browsers.
Here is my code:

```
var _addChangedProperty = function(input){
    input.changed = false;
    var oninput = function(){
        this.changed = !!this.value;
        if(this.changed){
            this.style.color = "black";
        }   
    };  
    input.onpropertychange = input.oninput = oninput;
};
```

Now I'd like to change `input.onpropertychange = input.oninput = oninput;` to `addEventListerner` and `attachEvent`, I need to check if `onpropertychange` event is supported, how could I do this (without browser detect)?

Comment: The Modernizr team apparently had trouble with it, but seem to have found a solution that successfully detects for it in all browsers. See the discussion on the Modernizr site here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/210

Answer (score 4):

You can check using the `in` operator:

```
"onpropertychange" in input
```

This kind of feature test doesn't work in older versions of Firefox, which report `false` event for event handler properties corresponding to events that do exist, but that isn't a problem here because Firefox doesn't currently support the `propertychange` event and is unlikely to in the future.

Here's some background: http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/

One other point: you need separate functions to handle the `propertychange` and `input` events, because in the `propertychange` handler you need to check whether it is the `value` property that has changed. Otherwise, you'll end up handling changes to any property of the input.

```
input.onpropertychange = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.propertyName == "value") {
        // Do stuff here
    }
};
```